# Is it possible to disable topic entirely in an org?

Tags: topics

I know we can disable topic for certain object, like account, by going to Setup->Topics->Topics for Objects.

Is it possible to disable topic entirely for an org?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable Topics from the **Topics for Objects** settings. So from **Setup** --> **Customize** (under Build)--> **Topics for Objects** you can enable of disable **Topics** for all obejcts.